# Getting the name of a field referenced by an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello Stackoverflow heroes,

I have an users table with the following field:
authorization_id

And i have an authorizations table with just a regular id. 
I tried renaming id to authorization_id but it just added another column called authorization_id it didn't change the id column.

What i am trying to achieve to be able to do

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
<tr>
<td><%= user.name %></td>
<td><%= user.authorization_id.name %></td>
<td><%= user.email %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
  <% if admin? %>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                                 :method => :delete %></td>
  <% end %> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

But it won't work i suspect that authorization_id is has not been linked to the autorizations table. But i can't seem to find out how to do it.

This is my authorization model

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3}
end
```

and this is a piece of my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         has_one :authorization
```

Any help will be welcomed,

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this:

```
  <td><%= user.authorization_id.name %></td>
```

Should simply be this:

```
  <td><%= user.authorization.name %></td>
```

You don't need `_id`.

Also, I think your associations are backwards (the `belongs_to` model should hold the foreign key). Check the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).

Comment: Ah great, i tried the one without the _id earlier, but didn't seem to work, it was because my association was backwards! Thanks for the quick anwser!

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer if you are so inclined. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Authorization` belongs to `User`, so the foreign key must be in `Authorization` model, eg we name it `user_id`.

So what we need to modify is add the foreign key `user_id` to `Authorization` model, that is enough.

Then your view is much easier:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.authorization.name %></td> <!-- Change here! -->
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <% if admin? %>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                                       :method => :delete %></td>
    <% end %> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```